# How can I repair ripped plasterboard paper

Tags: walls, patching-drywall

I was trying to remove wallpaper with the glue enzyme but I’ve ended up pulling large chunks of the plasterboard paper as well. I’m at a loss as how to repair it now. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Plasterboard with damaged surface paper]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that situation in commercial settings where wallpaper was removed. It's not that big a deal, assuming the material is still structurally sound. North American drywall would not be, as the paper facing is a critical component of the sheet.

If your wallboard still feels robust, do this:

1. Remove all loose and flaking paper using a putty knife or similar.
2. Seal the surface with a drywall primer/sealer.
3. Skim coat with joint compound or whatever folks use in your region.
4. Prime again.
5. Paint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed steps. 

For steps 2  and 3 will I be applying the sealer(and joint compound) to the whole wall or just the exposed “gray” concrete like area.

Comment: Just the repair area. I would seal (prime) the entire wall after repairs for a more consistent final coat.

Answer (score 3):

It can be really tough to get a smooth finish over this by coating with drywall compound but depending on how you plan to finish the wall that might be acceptable.

If you want a perfect finish, your best bet is going to be to cut the damaged section out and replace with fresh drywall.

But either way is going to be some work for you.